# Label `fig:rabbitmq-ha-policyfig' multiply defined in Mac OS Catalina using latexmk to compile

Tags: labels

When I compile my latex doc using this command in Mac OS Catalina:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode ./dolphin-book-2020.tex
```

it give me tips:

```
  Label `fig:rabbitmq-ha-policyfig' multiply defined
```

and I searching my docs and find only one places to define this like this:

```
另一种避免的方式是RabbitMQ HA，做镜像队列(Mirror Queue)，如图\ref{fig:rabbitmq-ha-policyfig}所示。

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{rabbitmq-ha-policy}
    \caption{RabbitMQ添加高可用策略}
    \label{fig:rabbitmq-ha-policyfig}
\end{figure}
```

why still give me tips mutidefined label and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: In terms of label defintions, the code shown in the question is fine. It should only define the label `fig:rabbitmq-ha-policyfig` once. Double check that there is no other figure (or something else) in your document that uses the label `fig:rabbitmq-ha-policyfig`.

Comment: no,only this place defined this and ref this label in the whole document.@moewe

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Is there a chance you can turn the code you have shown so far into a fully compilable example document that reproduces the warning (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? It is tricky to diagnose problems like this with only a part of the code, especially if the code on its own (if embedded into a simple document) is unproblematic.